# extract numerical values from strings in list that come directly after the "@ " symbol

Tags: python, regex, list, extract

I have a list that looks like this: * I have put each element on a new, numbered line for readability*

- ```
  NOVO NORDISK A/S    216757.000 SHS @ 5.15000000 EXDTE-22MAR19 PAYDTE-26MAR19 TAXABLE RECLAIMABLE TAXED AT .270000%,
  ```
- ```
  NOVO NORDISK A/S    205395.000 SHS @ 3.00000000 EXDTE-16AUG19 PAYDTE-20AUG19 TAXABLE RECLAIMABLE TAXED AT .270000%,
  ```
- ```
  NOVO NORDISK A/S    TAX RECLAIM PAID 79000.000 EX-DT:20MAR15 PY-DT:24MAR15 CURRENCY TIP # 1150790014348SIEMENS AG    89789.000 SHS @ 3.80000000 EXDATE-31JAN19 PAYDATE-04FEB19 TAXABLE RECLAIMABLE TAXED AT .263750%,
  ```
- ```
  UNILEVER NV    171208.000 SHS @ 0.38720000 EXDATE-14FEB19 PAYDATE-20MAR19 TAXABLE W/H @ SOURCE TAXED AT .150000%,
  ```
- ```
  ROYAL DUTCH SHELL PLC A SHS   568644.000 SHS @ 0.41810000 EXDTE-14FEB19 PAYDTE-25MAR19 TAXABLE W/H @ SOURCE TAXED AT .150000%,
  ```

I am trying to write a script that will extract the number that falls directly after the first "@" sign.
how would i go about doing this in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up on regex module re in python.

```py
import re

l = '''NOVO NORDISK A/S    216757.000 SHS @ 5.15000000 EXDTE-22MAR19 PAYDTE-26MAR19 TAXABLE RECLAIMABLE TAXED AT .270000%,
 NOVO NORDISK A/S    205395.000 SHS @ 3.00000000 EXDTE-16AUG19 PAYDTE-20AUG19 TAXABLE RECLAIMABLE TAXED AT .270000%,
 NOVO NORDISK A/S    TAX RECLAIM PAID 79000.000 EX-DT:20MAR15 PY-DT:24MAR15 CURRENCY TIP # 1150790014348SIEMENS AG    89789.000 SHS @ 3.80000000 EXDATE-31JAN19 PAYDATE-04FEB19 TAXABLE RECLAIMABLE TAXED AT .263750%,
 UNILEVER NV    171208.000 SHS @ 0.38720000 EXDATE-14FEB19 PAYDATE-20MAR19 TAXABLE W/H @ SOURCE TAXED AT .150000%,
 ROYAL DUTCH SHELL PLC A SHS   568644.000 SHS @ 0.41810000 EXDTE-14FEB19 PAYDTE-25MAR19 TAXABLE W/H @ SOURCE TAXED AT .150000%,'''

print(re.findall(r'(?<=@)\s*\d*[.]\d*',l))
```

EDIT: I didn't realize that you have substrings in a list, so here's one for that.

```py
import re

mylist = ['NOVO NORDISK A/S    216757.000 SHS @ 5.15000000 EXDTE-22MAR19 PAYDTE-26MAR19 TAXABLE RECLAIMABLE TAXED AT .270000%',
        'NOVO NORDISK A/S    205395.000 SHS @ 3.00000000 EXDTE-16AUG19 PAYDTE-20AUG19 TAXABLE RECLAIMABLE TAXED AT .270000%',
        'NOVO NORDISK A/S    TAX RECLAIM PAID 79000.000 EX-DT:20MAR15 PY-DT:24MAR15 CURRENCY TIP # 1150790014348SIEMENS AG    89789.000 SHS @ 3.80000000 EXDATE-31JAN19 PAYDATE-04FEB19 TAXABLE RECLAIMABLE TAXED AT .263750%',
        'UNILEVER NV    171208.000 SHS @ 0.38720000 EXDATE-14FEB19 PAYDATE-20MAR19 TAXABLE W/H @ SOURCE TAXED AT .150000%',
        'ROYAL DUTCH SHELL PLC A SHS   568644.000 SHS @ 0.41810000 EXDTE-14FEB19 PAYDTE-25MAR19 TAXABLE W/H @ SOURCE TAXED AT .150000%']

results = [re.search(r'(?<=@)\s*\d*[.]\d*',string).group() for string in mylist]

for res in results:
    print(res)
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked once i moved the .group() to:    Results = [re.search(r'(?<=@)\s*\d*[.]\d*',string) for string in my_list]

for res in Results:
    print(res.group())

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
my_list = ['NOVO NORDISK A/S    216757.000 SHS @ 5.15000000 EXDTE-22MAR19 PAYDTE-26MAR19 TAXABLE RECLAIMABLE TAXED AT .270000%',
'NOVO NORDISK A/S    205395.000 SHS @ 3.00000000 EXDTE-16AUG19 PAYDTE-20AUG19 TAXABLE RECLAIMABLE TAXED AT .270000%']
result = [re.findall(r'\@ (\d+\.\d+)',s)[0] for s in my_list]
result
['5.15000000', '3.00000000']
```